# Jquery id property value is undefined

Tags: jquery

How can I access id property value of the selected element using the find method in `jquery`. I am trying like this

```
let attrId = $(this).prev().find(".selectpicker");
let  attrId2 = attrId.attr("id");
alert(attrId2);
```

But getting `undefined`

Updated:

Html:

```
<div>
    <select name="APPLIEDSHIP" id="APPLIEDSHIP_ID" class="selectpicker bs-select-hidden" multiple="" data-actions-box="true" data-live-search="true" data-placeholder="No Filter" data-width="170px" data-size="5">...</select>
</div>

<button style="margin-left: 5px; margin-top: 5px;" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">
    Print Id Of Selectpicker
</button>
```

**Using the above button I want to access select element's id**

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: check that `attrId` is not undefined first

Comment: Can you provide us with html code? Because while using prev, next, parent you should be very careful.

Comment: Please show your HTML (at least the relevant part), and tell us what `$(this)` refers to (or better, show the event handler).

Comment: I have updated @Jeto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit (after your own): your selector should work.

Demo:

```js
$(function () {
  $('.btn-info').on('click', function () {
    let attrId = $(this).prev().find('.selectpicker');
    let attrId2 = attrId.attr("id");
    alert(attrId2);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select name="APPLIEDSHIP" id="APPLIEDSHIP_ID" class="selectpicker bs-select-hidden"></select>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">Print Id Of Selectpicker</button>
```

Comment: @BabluAhmed Updated my answer, your selector should work as is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$(this).prev(".selectpicker")` to find previous element of clicked element.

Please see this Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/wjrmzs8b/